# I would like to know what this sentence means

Tags: meaning

What does the sentence in bold mean? I have given my thoughts under the paragraph

Advances in technology are creating the next economy and enabling us to make things/do things/connect with others in smarter, cheaper, faster, more effective ways. **But the price of this progress has been a decoupling of the engine of prosperity from jobs that have been the means by which people have ascended to (and stayed in) the middle class.**

I think what the author is saying is that as technology continues to improve, jobs that millions of middle class people do (truck driving, day care, cleaning etc) may become useless or obsolete.

Comment: "a decoupling of the engine of prosperity from jobs..." is a windbag's way of saying "advances in technology have eliminated many jobs in the salary range that would enable the worker to enter the middle class and remain there".  You are on the right track with "obsolete".  Although day-care cannot be automated: babies having their diapers changed by droids?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Breaking your sentence apart

> But the price of this progress
>   *the unwanted consequence of this progress*
>
> has been a decoupling of
>   *has been the change in relationship of how this progress relates to*
>
> the engine of prosperity
>   *how people became richer*
>
> from jobs that have been
>   *the types of jobs*
>
> the means by which
>   *that have enabled the possibility of*
>
> people have ascended to (and stayed in) the middle class.
>   *people moving up into or staying within the middle class*

You are correct in understanding that technology is allowing greater productivity at a lower cost and thereby either replaces human jobs or causes downward pressure in wages.  This is primarily happening in lower skilled labor market (lower and low-middle class) jobs.

For example, autonomous cars may do away with many taxi driver jobs which historically have been filled by new immigrants.